# I want to add two words which will be at left and right end and also are equally offset from the margins

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pdftex, koma-script

I have two words in a line which i want to show them on left and right side and leave 10mm space on both sides.

How to do this

I am trying the following code:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=false,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:305.72468pt,DIV=calc,paper=landscape}
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 305.72468pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}

\noindent[17-20/44][1/6][1-2/2][23-26/50][4-7/12]\hfill5x[16/16][1/1]

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With KOMA class option `parskip=full` applied, there is always an at least 1em free space at the end of the last line of the paragraph. See documentation of KOMA-script, Table 3.7.

If you want to let the single line containing `[17-20/44]...` being a paragraph, then some calculation is required. Here I add `\hspace*{10mm}` at the beginning of that line, and `\hspace*{\dimexpr10mm-1em\relax}` at the end.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=false,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:305.72468pt,DIV=calc,paper=landscape}
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 305.72468pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}

\noindent\hspace*{10mm}[17-20/44][1/6][1-2/2][23-26/50][4-7/12]\hfill 5x[16/16][1/1]\hspace*{\dimexpr10mm-1em\relax}\par

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also i dont want any paragraph spacing between this para and the next.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi It seems what you want is a page header, is it?

Comment: No, Even in between i want to add like that.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi Appending `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` to `...[1/1]\hspace*{\dimexpr10mm-1em\relax}\par` will reduce the extra vertical space. Although I suggest you to describe the bigger picture of your requirement and ask for a whole solution, perhaps in a new question.

Comment: Anyhow i used `\parskip=0pt` before `\blindtext` and it removed the paragraph spacing. If i remove

Comment: Can you explain what is `\hspace*{\dimexpr10mm-1em\relax}\par` and how does it work

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi `\hspace*{<dimension>}` inserts a non-discardable space of width `<dimension>`, `\dimexpr<dimension expression>\relax` computes the result of given `<dimension expression>`. `\hspace` is a LaTeX macro, see its doc in https://latexref.xyz/_005chspace.html#g_t_005chspace; `\dimexpr` is an eTeX primitive and is documented in [eTeX's doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/etex/etex_man.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\hspace{10mm}ABCD\hfill XYZ\hspace{10mm}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=false,footsepline=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=432pt:305.72468pt,DIV=calc,paper=landscape}
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 305.72468pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm}

\hspace{10mm}[17-20/44][1/6][1-2/2][23-26/50][4-7/12]\hfill5x[16/16][1/1]\hspace{10mm}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: i tried yours, I get a slight different spacing. The image is https://0x0.st/igrL.png

Comment: With class option `parskip=full`, an extra horizontal space of 1em is added at the end of last of a paragraph, hence `XYZ\hspace{10mm}` actually produces a space of width  `10mm+1em`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, why this is not a case at paragraph with `\blindtext`?

Comment: @Zarko It is. See the _last_ line in the single paragraph produced by `\blindtext`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, last line in `blindtext` doesn't show this (as far as I can see).  I'm not familiar with KOMA classes, this behavior is strange. To me this looks as bug.

Comment: @Zarko I guess the behavior is, if the remaining space at the last line of a paragraph is not less than 1em, then nothing happens. This is the case of `\blindtext`, which ends with  `...accumsan smper.` I'm not sure if we are talking about the same "last line".

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, apparently we are not talking about the same thing. Since I'm not familiar with KOMA, I will live with this special (to me strange)  features of it :-)

Comment: In general, it helps to add a \noindent at the start.